# Testnig PWA using selenium-webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, progressive-web-apps, ui-automation

I there a way how to test desktop PWA application using selenium-webdriver? I'm especially interested in install application(when the application installed as native application + desktop icon is added), open application as native application.  Can I somehow perform this actions using webdriver?

The "Install application" dialog cannot be controlled by the webdriver's functions. I've also tried to open "chrome://apps/" url to handle the already installed application, but without any success.

Comment: sounds like you'd want Appium for that.  (You'd use Selenium and a type of driver for your OS.)